# Creating image from 2 images

Tags: php

I am trying to create an image using 2 different PNG images but I can't get it to work. There are no errors or anything but I didn't get an image created.

Also, is it possible to place some text on the final image and then save it (hardcode text into it)?

Test sample

```
<?php
    $image_1 = imagecreatefrompng('assets/img/image_body.png');
    $image_2 = imagecreatefrompng('assets/img/img_2.png');
    imagealphablending($image_1, true);
    imagesavealpha($image_1, true);
    imagecopy($image_1, $image_2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    imagepng($image_1, 'image_3.png');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed images location with

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

This Code is working.

```
<?php
// This .php file is inside root>NP
$LOC = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$image_1 = imagecreatefrompng($LOC . '/NP/m1.png');
$image_2 = imagecreatefrompng($LOC . '/NP/m2.png');
imagealphablending($image_1, true);
imagesavealpha($image_1, true);
imagecopy($image_1, $image_2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 640, 400);
imagepng($image_1, $LOC.'/NP/m3.png');
?>
```

Comment: What does location has to do with it tho?